# Pushing Code to Github for the second time

Tags: angular, github

I did build successfully my angular code and was able to publish it to the Github repository.
while publishing I also mentioned directory to be dist/projectname
So I can see in Github repository Gh-Pages only my dist folder.
Now I want to also push complete code to the GitHub repository.
What should be the commands I need to execute so it can be pushed for the second time and complete code

I think since I am pushing for the second time so it would be a different scenario

I expect that code is pushed and dist code under gh -pages gets overwritten

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Git add git commit git push?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I want to understand what exactly i need to do, as i a new GitHub user and don't want to mess up the online contents

Comment: But simply pushing will overwrite the code , is it so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following commands to save the new version to GitHub.

1. `git status` : Shows the details of the modified files.
2. `git add <filename | .>` : Add the file / files that you want to push to GitHub.
3. `git commit -m"<message>"` : Add a message for the commit.
4. `git push` : Push the commit to GitHub

Once you do this the code in the repository will be updated with the version that you pushed.

Comment: Perfect Response sir, this was what i was looking for
One more thing , if i want complete application to go onto Repository then "git add . " should be the command , am i correct

Comment: NET SEARCHED: git add . adds all modified and new (untracked) files in the current directory and all subdirectories to the staging area (a.k.a. the index), thus preparing them to be included in the next git commit

Comment: @NikhilMittal Yes `git add .`  will add all the files. Add the files that you don't want to commit to the `.gitignore` file before doing git add.

Answer (score 0):

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "update"
3. git push

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything not already covered by the accepted answer from a few years ago. Please be sure to review existing questions before answering, and only add a new answer if you have something substantially different or more to contribute.